# How Google puts unwanted apps on our Macs?

Tags: macos, applications, google-chrome, google, chrome-extensions

I cannot find in my memory a situation when I was installing anything from Google except from Google Chrome (that is my main browser).

Recently I saw on my Mac an app titled **Google Search.app**.

[image]

(Above screenshot taken from Launchpad)

Tiny **(87 KB)** but in my case definitely unwanted. I see that the only thing it does when opened is open Chrome with a new tab which has `google.com` for its url.

This makes no sense to me. Also this app is not stored in my home directory `/Users/slick/Applications/Chrome Apps`. Rather, it is stored in `/Applications`. Will definitely land into the Trash.

**Question:** How it was installed without my permission (if I'm a root on my own computer)? How should I stop this in future?

Comment: Maybe when you installed Chrome, you were prompted for your password, and after you typed it, Chrome installed several applications and scripts in your machine instead of what you thought would be just one? Also, placing an application in the trash doesn't uninstall all of it, you sometimes need to use an application cleaner to do a more thorough job.

Comment: I do know this probably won't help, but are you an administrator or are you logged into the System Administrator (root) account? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The "apps" come bundled with Chrome. These aren't actual apps, just links to Google services that are wrapped to look like a standard app (think of the as the OS equivalent of browser bookmarks to Google sites). You can safely delete them, but they will likely reappear should you re/install Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably also have Gmail, Google Drive and Youtube icons next to the Google Search icon.  They are bookmark icons that are installed automatically when you install a newer version of Chrome.

They're indeed not in `/Applications` but they are under your home directory.
You can find/delete them in `${HOME}/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized`